# Having hyphenated names in Jquery post method

Tags: jquery, post

After times of failing I found out that I cannot have hyphenated paremeter names in post method of jquery like this:

```
        $.post("/test",
        {
            subject: $('#subject').val(),
            email:  $('#email').val(),
            message: $('#message').val(),
            g-recaptcha-response = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
        }
```

the "g-recaptcha-response" is related to Google Recaptcha so naming is out of my hands. Is there any way that we can send a hyphenated parameter in this context?

Although there are other ways to work around this limit like submitting a form but I am curious if I can send it this way.

Comment: Use `'g-recaptcha-response'` instead

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with jQuery. It is javascript.

So use `'g-recaptcha-response'` instead:

```
$.post("/test", {
    subject: $('#subject').val(),
    email:  $('#email').val(),
    message: $('#message').val(),
    'g-recaptcha-response': $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
}
```

Also notice that it should be with `:` like this:

```
'g-recaptcha-response': $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
```

and not with `=` as you have it in your snippet:

```
'g-recaptcha-response' = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val()
```